# Create Album with React Native CameraRoll

Tags: ios, react-native, camera-roll

With ReactNative CameraRoll, you can save a photo/video to an existing album on your device's camera roll. Is there a way to create the album, if it does not yet exist, before saving to it?

Comment: Would like to know the answer to this as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the react native [react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll](https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll) package and call `CameraRoll.save({type: "photo", album: "newAlbumTest"})`, (where "newAlbumTest" is an album that did not exist before) this will automatically create a new album on the user's CameraRoll.